# Enviar geolocalização para webservice e atualizar em outros dispositivos

Tags: android, web-service

Bem não consegui chegar a um título bom para a pergunta.

Mas estou com o seguinte problema, estou querendo fazer um app como o Easy Taxi, pegarei a localização do cliente e enviarei para os 'franqueados'.

A dúvida é, devo ficar atualizando no banco de dados a cada minuto por exemplo a localização do franqueado? Teria outra forma de se fazer sem salvar isso em um banco?

Comment: Isso é questão de escolha e design seus. Você só precisa guardar no banco se quiser ler essa informação do banco. E a frequência de atualização ideal você só encontra com experimentos.

Answer (score 1):

Salvar os dados no banco de dados será uma opção caso queira usá-los para análises posteriores.
Mas você pode muito bem compartilhar esses dados para o cliente sem ter de fazer algum trabalho de persistência de dados, como por exemplo:

- Armazenar a posição atual do franqueado em uma lista que contém todos as solicitações atuais e de acordo com a frequência programada essa posição do franqueado ser atualizada na lista. Essa mesma lista será usada para capturar a posição atual do franqueado e enviar para o cliente.

Sobre enviar a geolocalização do cliente para os franqueados, após estar disponível no servidor para distruibio entre os franqueados, você pode usar alguns padrões de envio como:

- [Google Cloud Message](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html);
- Long Polling;
- [WebSocket](https://www.websocket.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja uma questão de arquitetura. Você poderia utilizar um pattern de integração chamado [publish/subscribe](http://www.eaipatterns.com/PublishSubscribeChannel.html).

Utilizando um sistema de mensagens, por exemplo JMS, você poderia utilizar um tópico.

O sistema cliente "publica" a localização no tópico criado. Esta informação é recebida por todos os "sistemas inscritos" neste tópico.